# Deleting rows based on cell value in a certain column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel VBA project.

I delete multiple rows when the cell in Column B is blank. And the code is as follows:

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Now, I would like to delete multiple rows when the cell value in Column E is not a number.

Could you help me with a code similar to the one above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SpecialCells` can select other cell type too:

```
Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, _
  xlTextValues + xlLogical + xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
```

and/or

```
Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, _
  xlTextValues + xlLogical + xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
```